# Program is working with integers, but not with doubles

Tags: types, integer, double

I'm supposed to input real numbers until a input of 0 is encountered, then program should terminate. I got this code working for integer data type:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int a[60];

    for(i=0;i<60;i++)
        a[i]=-1;

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]==0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But when I try the same code on the double data type, program termination does not occur on input of 0. Here's the code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    double a[60];

    for(i=0;i<60;i++)
        a[i]=-1.0;

    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        scanf("%f",&a[i]);
        if(a[i]==0.0)
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Would anyone bother to explain why is this so? I can't think of any reason. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a `printf("%f",a[i])` after the `scanf`, to see what your program makes of your input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, your parse string is incorrect: for double it should be "%lf", not "%f", which is for floats.

Secondly, in general comparing floating-point types for equality is error-prone because they are by nature approximative, although in this case, 0 is a value that can be represented exactly.

Comment: Thank You. The thing is, I thought about my conversion specifier being wrong, but failed to actually realize where the problem is. Thanks once again.